# Recursive University Assignment gives decreasion grade with no explanation

Tags: c, recursion

So this is a code I wrote for an Assignment I published and got 100 for BUT before getting 100, I actually got 96!

The change I made to get the 4 points and round my grade to 100 is with this line:

```
FindCommonDigit(n1 / 10, n2 / 10, arr, sumCommon);
```

At the beginning this line place where "//Test3 (-4)" is right now and that's what caused the decrease of the 4 points.

What I'm trying to understand is... What can actually cause the system to decrease the grade with -4 points just because of the place of the line:

```
FindCommonDigit(n1 / 10, n2 / 10, arr, sumCommon);
```

Thanks in advance guys and hope you have a great day :)

The code I got 100 with:

```
void FindCommonDigit(unsigned long n1, unsigned long n2, int arr[], int* sumCommon)
{
    /*Write your code down here*/
    if (n1 <= 0 || n2 <= 0)
        return;

    if (n1 % 10 < n2 % 10) 
        FindCommonDigit(n1, n2 / 10, arr, sumCommon);
    else if (n2 % 10 < n1 % 10) 
        FindCommonDigit(n1 / 10, n2, arr, sumCommon);

    if (n1 % 10 == n2 % 10) {
        if (*sumCommon == 0)
        {
            arr[*sumCommon] = n1 % 10;
            (*sumCommon)++;
        }
        if (n1 % 10 != arr[(*sumCommon)-1])
        {
            arr[*sumCommon] = n1 % 10;
            (*sumCommon)++;
        }
        FindCommonDigit(n1 / 10, n2 / 10, arr, sumCommon);
    }
    //Test3 (-4)
}
```

The code I got 96 with:

```
void FindCommonDigit(unsigned long n1, unsigned long n2, int arr[], int* sumCommon)
    {
        /*Write your code down here*/
        if (n1 <= 0 || n2 <= 0)
            return;
    
        if (n1 % 10 < n2 % 10) 
            FindCommonDigit(n1, n2 / 10, arr, sumCommon);
        else if (n2 % 10 < n1 % 10) 
            FindCommonDigit(n1 / 10, n2, arr, sumCommon);
    
        if (n1 % 10 == n2 % 10) {
            if (*sumCommon == 0)
            {
                arr[*sumCommon] = n1 % 10;
                (*sumCommon)++;
            }
            if (n1 % 10 != arr[(*sumCommon)-1])
            {
                arr[*sumCommon] = n1 % 10;
                (*sumCommon)++;
            }
        }
        FindCommonDigit(n1 / 10, n2 / 10, arr, sumCommon);
    }
```

Comment: The comment should be stripped out by the preprocessor before it gets compiled so should have no effect on the execution. I'm not sure what happened. Hard to tell why you're getting different results without seeing the tests and what you're feeding in as arguments.

Comment: May be each time test cases changes, and code do not seems to find all common digits if input is not in ascending order.

Comment: What was the assignment? Did they tell you the tests? What was Test3? It sounds like your program gave the wrong answer for Test #3 which is why you lost points.

Comment: @user253751 , Forget about the "//Test3 (-4)" ..
The code is the same except the location that the last recursive command is placed at which leads to -4 points and I want to know what could be the reason for that since the university system doesn't provide further information about the reasons for downgrade.

Comment: @RyanOtweeng Did they tell you what the tests were? If they didn't, then it's *your* job to think of some numbers to run your function with, and make sure your function creates the correct output for those numbers.

Comment: @user253751 , We also get a main.c with simple tests which worked with the function but when you upload the project to the submission site they make more test in the background so I can't know which tests they're doing.. This's why I publish my code for :)

Comment: @RyanOtweeng Try making up some of your own tests. See if you can invent some tests where the placement of the recursive call would make a difference.